# Getting a value in a dictionary ordered by value datetime?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the account that hasn't been used for the most time.

Is there a way I can edit the `bestAccount` variable to check Activity disctionary and if it does contain the key to get the one with the oldest DateTime?

```
public class AuthHandler : IAuthHandler
{
    public IDictionary<string, DateTime> Activity;
    public IDictionary<string, string> Accounts;

    public AuthHandler()
    {
        Activity = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
        Accounts = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public KeyValuePair<string, string> Generate()
    {
        var bestAccount = Accounts.Where(x => !Activity.ContainsKey(x.Key)).FirstOrDefault();
        Activity[bestAccount.Key] = DateTime.Now;

        return bestAccount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following:

```
var bestAccount = Accounts.Where(a => !Activity.ContainsKey(a.Key))
                                           .OrderByDescending(a => a.Value).FirstOrDefault();

if (bestAccount != null)
{
    doSomething();
}
```

For more info, refer to the docs available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Thanks, is there an easy way to check if this is null? I am getting `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'KeyValuePair<string, string>' and '<null>'`

Comment: You cannot use that operator for KeyValuePair, I validated it using `bestAccount.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, string>))` thanks.